Does Bing Spell Check API perform spell checks for Asian languages?
When using Bing's Spell Check API I find that there are no results provided for certain Asian languages. Using a string that I verified as incorrect from a native speaker, I would expect that with the mkt=zh to return some suggestions for correcting this.
Here is the Postman setup I am using
While searching for answers I have yet to actually find what languages are supported by Bing. The term "market" and associated codes isn't fully clear if that denotes the language being checked, or if it's just a location marker. It isn't even required by the API https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bing-docs/blob/main/bing-docs/bing-spell-check/reference/query-parameters.md#mkt
Has anyone here ever attempted to use this product for Chinese language spell checking?
